# Why do small enough balls have this geodesic property in Riemannian Geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I am learning the basics of Riemannian Geometry and my teacher invokes multiple times the following proposition :

*For any $p \in M$, there exists an open subset $U \ni p$ with the property that any two points $\alpha, \beta$ in $U$ are linked by a unique distance-minimizing geodesic in $M$.*

Here, $M$ is a $m$-dimensional connected Riemannian manifold. (Maybe my teacher also assumes $M$ is complete, I am not sure).

My question is : why is this true ? We proved two related things in class : the statement about existence is true if $\alpha = p$ (proved by considering the exponential map $exp_p : \Omega_p \subseteq TM_p \to M$ - but we did not show uniqueness) ; and we saw the Hopf-Rinow theorem. How do we put the pieces together ?

Comment: It will be covered in any riemannian geometry textbook. Which one are you reading?